WP Rest API to ACF custom fields
I tried to update custom post fields using rest api, enable rest api though setting of custom fields but they don't auto populate the fileds like car_id, car_URL but the title is populating correctly. I checked the data from external API it is gathering data in all variables perfectly. Please help me identify this and I would appreciate your help!
<button class="add-to-favorite-button">Add to Favorite</button>


<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    $("#btloader").hide();
    var url = window.location.href;
    var all_datas = url.split("?carID=");
    var idvalue = all_datas[1];

    // Fetch car details from API
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://phpstack-1191307-4547932.cloudwaysapps.com/frontend_api/car_details/index.php",
        data: {
            idvalue: idvalue,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var carName = `${data.general_type} ${data.vin_year} ${data.vin_make} ${data.vin_model} ${data.vin_trim} ${data.drivetrain} ${data.vin_style_desc}`;
            var carFirstImage = ''; // Placeholder for the car image
            var carDescription = data.std_description;
            var carURL = window.location.href;

            // Fetch the car gallery to get the first image
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://phpstack-1191307-4547932.cloudwaysapps.com/frontend_api/car_details/gallery.php",
                data: {
                    idvalue: idvalue,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#big_gallery").html(data);
                    carFirstImage = $("#big_gallery img").first().attr('src');
                    setupFavoriteButton(carName, carFirstImage, carURL, idvalue);
                },
            });
        },
    });

    function setupFavoriteButton(carName, carFirstImage, carURL, carID) {
        const addButton = document.querySelector('.add-to-favorite-button');

        // Function to check if the car is already in favorites
        function checkFavorite(carID) {
            fetch('/wp-json/wp/v2/favorite_cars?meta_key=car_id&meta_value=' + carID, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        addButton.textContent = 'Remove from Favorite';
                        addButton.dataset.favoriteId = data[0].id;
                    }
                });
        }

        checkFavorite(carID);

        addButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            if (addButton.textContent === 'Add to Favorite') {
                fetch('/wp-json/wp/v2/favorite_cars', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'X-WP-Nonce': wpApiSettings.nonce
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        title: carName,
                        status: 'publish',
                        // Include additional fields using ACF field names
                        fields: {
                            car_id: carID,
                            car_url: carURL,
                            car_name: carName,
                            car_first_image: carFirstImage
                        }
                    })
                })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        addButton.textContent = 'Remove from Favorite';
                        addButton.dataset.favoriteId = data.id;
                        alert('Car added to favorites!');
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                    });
            } else {
                const favoriteId = addButton.dataset.favoriteId;
                fetch(`/wp-json/wp/v2/favorite_cars/${favoriteId}`, {
                    method: 'DELETE',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'X-WP-Nonce': wpApiSettings.nonce
                    }
                })
                    .then(() => {
                        addButton.textContent = 'Add to Favorite';
                        alert('Car removed from favorites!');
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                    });
            }
        });
    }
});


</script>

I tried using acf instead of fields in below, also tried using fields keys but same issue. it is not adding the data.
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        title: carName,
                        status: 'publish',
                        // Include additional fields using ACF field names
                        fields: {
                            car_id: carID,
                            car_url: carURL,
                            car_name: carName,
                            car_first_image: carFirstImage

